# thread management in C

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault

*defining the struct*

```
typedef struct {
    int a,b;
}targ;
```

1st thread function:

```
void* sum(void *arg) {
    int *s;
    targ *p = (targ*)arg;

    int i=p->a;
    int j=p->b;
    *s=i+j;
    pthread_exit((void*)s);
}
```

2nd thread function:

```
void* pdt(void *arg) {
    int *p;
    targ *s= (targ*)arg;

    int i=s->a;
    int j=s->b;
    *p=i*j;
     pthread_exit((void*)p);
 }
```

Main thread function:

```
 int main(void) {
     int ret1,ret2;
     pthread_t tid1,tid2;
     targ *x;

     x=(targ*)malloc(sizeof(targ));

     printf("enter the 2 numbers\n");
     scanf("%d%d",&x->a,&x->b);

     printf("%d%d",x->a,x->b);

     pthread_create(&tid1,NULL,sum,(void*)x);
     pthread_create(&tid2,NULL,pdt,(void*)x);

     pthread_join(tid1,(void**)&ret1);
     pthread_join(tid2,(void**)&ret2);

     printf("the sum and product of the 2 numbers is %d and %d\n",(int)ret1,    (int)ret2);

     return 0;
 }
```

I'm not able to understand why there's a *segfault* even though I have followed the *man* pages for each API.

The program is to understand how thread functions work with one another. The main function passes the values to each thread function and they return back a value to the main function.

Comment: You don't allocate `p` and `s` (the integers) anywhere, so they will be pointers with random contents, meaning they'll pointing to a random location in memory and (extremely likely) trigger a segfault on access. You should also declare `ret1` and `ret2` as int pointers, if you pass their address to `pthread_join`, and accordingly dereference them in `printf` then.

Answer (score 3):

You have not allocated memory for the s and p pointer variables. So the segmentation fault happened.
You should allocate memory or use the address only.

Answer (score 1):

Your method of returning and printing the return values from the threads is not correct. I will show the step by step solution for one thread. The other has the same solution.

In the thread function `sum`, allocate some memory for an int variable, then store the result in the memory pointer to by `s`.

```
int *s = malloc( sizeof(int) );
*s=i+j
```

Then return the pointer to that memory.

```
return s;
```

Now you need to collect the pointer returned from the thread correctly.

The function pthread_join requires a pointer to a pointer to void as the second argument. You are passing a pointer to an int. This is incorrect even though the cast suppresses the error. Instead use a pointer to void and pass its address to the function:

```
void* ret1 = NULL;
pthread_join(tid1, &ret1);
```

The pointer `ret1` now points to the same memory, pointer `s` pointed to in the thread. That memory holds the result of the calculation. Declare a pointer to int and store pointer to that memory in it:

```
int* sm = ret1;
```

Then print the value:

```
printf( "%d\n" , *sm );
```

After it is not needed anymore the memory allocated in the function `sum`(Look at the malloc call above) should be freed:

```
free( sm );
```